# hyperpower modular

Tags: arithmetic

How can I calculate this?
${(p-1)}^{{(p-2)^{{(p-3)}^{(p-4)...}}}} (mod {.p}) $

and so on till 1.
I don't know how to write it with a Knuth or Ackerman or more compact notation.

I've tried to find a pattern evaluating it with Mathematica, Pari, GMP, or Magma.

2 mod 3 =   2

3^2 mod 4 = 1

4^3^2 mod 5= 4

5^4^3^2 mod 6 = 1

6^5^4^3^2 mod 7 =   6

But the next step always produces an overflow.

7^6^5^4^3^2 mod 8 =  ?? (  I guess it equals 1).

I guess there should be some workaround.

cheers

PD:
I think I've found a way to solve some of these problems. I didn't find it myself but I found it on the Internet. Using ai≡aj(modm)⇔i≡j(mode). Where e is the multiplicative order, e=ordm(a), that's the smallest k that makes ak≡1(modm), And it can be used only if gcd(a,m)=1

Answer (score 6):

If $p$ is even, then $(p-2)^{{(p-3)}^{\ldots}}$ is an even exponent, and so we have $(p-1)^{{(p-2)}^{\ldots}} \equiv (-1)^{{(p-2)}^{\dots}} \equiv 1 \mod p$. If $p$ is odd, then $(p-2)^{\ldots}$ is an odd exponent, and so $(p-1)^{{(p-2)}^{\ldots}} \equiv (-1)^{{(p-2)}^{\ldots}} \equiv -1 \mod p$.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't notice that I wrote (mod p). How would you solve it if it were (mod N), with N being any integer positive number?

Comment: That's actually what I've calculated, though I was using the same notation as you were. Just inspect the parity of the exponent, which is all that matters, since $N-1$ (if we're changing notation) is equivalent to $-1 \mod N$.

Comment: For example how much is ...?
$8^{7^{6^{5^{4^{3^{2}}}}}} \mod 17$

Comment: Or something maybe easier, 


$a \uparrow \uparrow b \mod c $
such as 
$7^{7^{7^{7^{7^{7^{7}}}}}} \mod 17$

Comment: I think I've found a way to solve some of these problems. I didn't find it myself but I found it on the Internet.
Using $a^i \equiv a^j \pmod {m} \Leftrightarrow{} i \equiv j \pmod{e}$.
Where e is the multiplicative order,
$e=ord_m (a)$,
that's the smallest k that makes
$a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$,
And it can be used only if $gcd(a,m)=1$